# [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I want to access the MS SQL Server and have the select query. I have installed the dll files and am using the `sqlsrv_query`. The connection has been successful but I get:

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object
>   name as error

I am using PHP version 5.3.1

After the connection I have this code

```
$sql = "SELECT id, latitude, longitude from job ";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      echo $row['latitude'].", ".$row['longitude']."<br />";
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
```

Answer (score 0):

"job" is a reserved word in SQL Server. Use this:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, latitude, longitude from [job] ";
```

Comment: I have used but still its not working.It gives the same message.**Invalid object name**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are connected to to correct database on the server, and that a table (or view or alias) named **job** exists in this database.

Comment: I have connected to it and the response is also successfully printed.But while I try to retrieve the value I get the problem.I have the job table and also I have tried with the other tables as well but gives the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute using the Database and Schema names like

> databaseName.schema.table

```
$sql = "SELECT id, latitude, longitude from [DB_Name].[dbo].[job]";
```

OR

only with `schema name: DBO` or any other

```
$sql = "SELECT id, latitude, longitude from [dbo].[job] ";
```